# Is there any way I can downcast an object in java like this?

Tags: java, casting

I'm new to java and I've been given an assignment Is there any way I can downcast Employee e to Teacher t without changing e at its declaration? I've searched the web but I couldn't find any way of doing it. Thanks.

```
class Person{
 String gender;
}

class Employee extends Person{
  String work;
}

class Teacher extends Employee{
   String Class;
}

public class Q1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
Employee e= new Employee();
Teacher t= new Teacher();
t= (Teacher) e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: You can't cast an object to an object type it doesn't belong to. `e` is holding a `new Employee()`. That object is not an instance of `Teacher`.

Comment: @GauravJeswani is right; the cast could work, but only if `Employee e` had been initialized with a `new Teacher()` instead of a `new Employee()`.

Comment: @Michael I did try it. It gives an error.

Comment: Thank you @khelwood